# How to get R to read data as categorical rather than continuous (for S4 models)

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I am running an unmarked occupancy model and one of my covariates is protected status. This covariate has 3 levels 0, 1 and 2. I need to take a model-averaged estimate of the effect of the covariate and occupancy. Currently, R is reading the covariate as a continuous rather than a categorical variable and so I need to adjust my code. Unfortunately, all the methods I can find on R for making data categorical rather than continuous are for 'S3 models' and this is an 'S4 model'. I have also tried telling R that the data is a factor like shown in the code below.

```
Site.Covs.Wolves2 <- read.csv("wolftotcovars40.csv", header = T, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

But when I tried to take a model-averaged estimate I got the error message

```
Some models include more than one instance of the parameter of interest. 
This may be due to the presence of interaction/polynomial terms, or variables
with similar names:
    see "?modavg" for details on variable specification and "exclude" argument
In addition: Warning message:
In modavg.AICunmarkedFitOccu(M.listTOT3, "Prot_Stat", parm.type = "psi") : 
Model names have been supplied automatically in the table
```

The data is 111 sites labelled 'TN1' 'TN2' 'TN3' etc. though this is removed before forming the occupancy frame so it's not related to that. I guess the issue is that there are multiple sites with the same protected status and so have the same 'factor value' but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.